# C7 to Bb in "I'll See You in my Dreams"

Tags: harmony

"I'll See You in my Dreams" verse to chorus seems awkward.

It’s shown as C7 To Bb but seems to need to go through F which is not shown on lead sheets. I’m a relative novice and grappling with this.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you just wondering if the chord changes you have are correct? (Also, adding punctuation to your post will make it much easier to understand.)

Comment: Welcome! Right now this question isn't clear enough to answer. Can you use the "edit" button to show or link to the lead sheet you're talking about?

Answer (score 7):

While the most common thing for a C7 chord to do is resolve as a dominant chord to a tonic F or Fm chord there are dozens of ways that dominant chords are used in music. Some are covered in functional diatonic harmony and some are not. Even though there are established functions for different types of chords there are no rules in music for what chord one should use or what chord should follow another chord.

In this particular case the C7 goes to Bb. It is not uncommon to go from a V chord to a IV chord. It happens in a large percentage of blues songs, not to mention the I IV V IV progression (think “La Bamba”).

Granted the pull is strong to the I (F) chord in this case because the V chord ends a section but this was intentional on the composers part. He created a surprise, a deceptive or delayed resolution to the I since it does end up there 2 bars later.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on @JohnBelzaguy's good answer: the pattern V7, IV7, I (or I7) is very common in the later bars of 12-bar and other blues. It is not a classical sound, but it does sound good. :)

In fact, a parallel descent, easier to notate in a particular key, say C, doing G7 Gb7(=f#7) F7 and then C7 is a good and standard blues-y sound.

Yes, it is possible to rationalize some of this in terms of secondary dominants, tritone substitutions, and such, but it is perhaps simpler for operational understanding to simply know the *sound* of these patterns, rather than looking for 18th-century-practice explanations. :)

(Believe me, I tried... :)

Answer (score 1):

There are so many different versions chord-wise, of this song!

However, in key F (it's been performed in just about every conceivable key!) the verse ends on V (C) or V7 (C7), as is often the case when there's another verse following. The 1st beat of the verse is actually a IV chord (on the word *see*).

At the end of the verse, comes the chorus. As in maybe the majority (?) of songs, the chorus (middle 8) will start on IV. It does here, on B♭.

So, yes, one might expect an F7 or even Cm7 between the verse end and the chorus, but it doesn't happen. It is shown in one version, and there's no reason not to use it, though. It's just what the writers wanted - leading the listener, perhaps, to expect another verse, or just a whim.

I suspect this is a case where some theory is known which makes what they wrote *wrong*! There is no *wrong* in music!

Comment: An F7 would imply that the chorus starts in Bb.  It doesn't.  It starts on the subdominant of F major.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - I thought that's what I put. On, not in.

Answer (score 0):

The first half of the verse establishes F major as tonic, ventures to D7, then 'cycle of 5ths' it's way back to F. All very standard.   Second half strays slightly further, the same 'cycle of 5ths' structure only gets as far as C7, setting us up nicely for a chorus back home in F major.  Still standard stuff.

And the chorus IS in F major.  There's no question of the B♭ and B♭m chords being tonicized, they're plainly IV and iv in the key of F.  It just doesn't start on the tonic chord.

Yes, you can do that.   'Sweet Georgia Brown' doesn't hit the tonic chord until bar 13 of the 16-bar chorus.

[image]